# Get current webview URL and login

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I try to get the current URL because when I put bad login in my app, I have the login page displayed. I don't  want this page to be displayed. So, I use the solution to get the current url and if this URL is http://www.example.com/account/login/ I want to create an action. But currently, when I try this solution, I have a null response.

```
 NSString * currentURL = _loadscreen.request.URL.absoluteString;
    if ([currentURL isEqualToString:@"http://www.example.com/account/login/"]) {
        NSLog(@"WARNING");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"URL is %@",currentURL); <- return (null).
    }
```

I use this code to auto-login users :

```
NSString *identifiant = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Identifiant"];
    NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Password"];
    if((identifiant) && (password))
    {
        //Configure URL
        NSString* host = @"http://www.example.com";
        NSString* complement = @"/account/login";



        NSString* user_name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Identifiant"];
        NSString* password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Password"];
        //Add URL + Folder
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", host, complement];


        //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];


        //NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        //Add some informations POST
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_name=%@&password=%@&submit=submit", user_name, password];;


        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];


        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];



        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
         {
             if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) [_loadscreen loadRequest:request];
             else if (error != nil) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];
    }
    else
    {


    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    NSString * currentURL = _loadscreen.request.URL.absoluteString;
    if ([currentURL isEqualToString:@"http://www.example.com/account/login/"]) {
        NSLog(@"WARNING");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"URL is %@",currentURL);
    }
```

It's work fine, if user put the good id, if not, the login page is displayed but I don't want.

Comment: have you check currentURL value ?

Comment: When I check currentURL value I have null value

Comment: try to print "_loadscreen.request.URL" value first

Comment: If it's my Login page displayed on the webview, the result should be http://www.example.com/account/login no ?

Comment: Yes. But what its give you vaue in nslog _loadscreen.request.URL

Comment: When I try , I have this result : `2015-07-05 21:06:49.906 APPNAME[6250:936862] URL is (null)`